# Create multiple instances of a specific resource using Cloud Formation Template

Tags: json, amazon-ec2, cloud, aws-cloudformation

Thanks in advance!
I'm trying to create 3 seperate Ec2 instances with say instance 1 running spark master, instance 2 has spark worker and instance 3 has client running in it using cloud formation template.

I want to have single instance for spark master, but multiple instances for spark workers with spark master host as user data parameter, How can I do that?

Regards,
Amey

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As per *AWS CloudFormation* docs:

> You must declare each resource separately; however, if you have
>   multiple resources of the same type, you can declare them together by
>   separating them with commas.

For passing in user data, you can use the `UserData` property of a resource.

**Reference:** http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resources-section-structure.html

**Edit 2019-07-15:** It appears that they've updated the AWS docs and taken away that snippet that I quoted. You'll have to define each EC2 instance separately in CloudFormation.

Comment: What does "separating them by commas" mean? A resource declaration for any resource has a whole bunch of key/value pairs in it. Which of these key/value pairs need to be separated by commas to declare "multiple resources"? Or is this identical to just, declaring two entire resources with different names? (And in this case, how does "the same type" even enter into it?)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have very specific reasons to do otherwise, I wouldn't recommend creating an Apache Spark cluster from scratch using EC2 and CloudFormation. Instead, I would look into setting up a Spark cluster using [Amazon EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/), which supports [Spark](https://aws.amazon.com/emmr/details/spark/) out of the box, and will save you from repeating a large amount of custom setup getting a Spark cluster configured and provisioned correctly. Using EMR, you can easily [choose the number and type of instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-instances.html), or even [auto scale](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-automatic-scaling.html) depending on your cluster's current load. Though using the Console is best for getting started, CloudFormation also supports EMR through its [`AWS::EMR::Cluster`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-emr-cluster.html) resource.

If you insist on using CloudFormation to launch EC2 instances directly, look at the [`AWS::EC2::Instance`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html) resource for your master/client, and [`AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html) resource for your worker pool.

Comment: Thanks @wjordan, Can you please give me an example of using AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup for Spark worker. Can AMI ID be specified in AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup like we can in AWS::EC2::Instance ?